# Assign a string value from one type to another type after using converting the string to upper case

Tags: typescript, enums, casting, uppercase

The first type:

```
declare type roles = 'admin' | 'user';
```

The other type

```
declare type ROLES = 'ADMIN' | 'USER';
```

I need to assign from the first to the second, this is my current code:

```
const r: roles = 'admin';
const R: ROLES = r.toUpperCase() as ROLES;
```

But I don't want to explicitly cast, is there any better workaround without enforcing the cast?

**EDIT:**
The solution I went with:

```
const r: roles = 'admin';
const R: ROLES = r.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<roles>;
```

With this approach, if later a new value added to `roles` but not `ROLES`, TS will complain about the mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, a cast is required somewhere. The built in `toUpperCase()` method returns the type `string`, even when you call it on a string literal value. So the type of the string literal you started with is lost when this is called.

You could pass the cast down the line a bit and make a generic function:

```
function toUpperCase<T extends string>(str: T): Uppercase<T> {
    return str.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<T>
}

const r: roles = 'admin';
const R: ROLES = toUpperCase(r); // works
```

But the cast is still required here for the same reason. But at least now the cast is not hardcoding your data model.

Whether this solution is an improvement over the `as ROLES` case is a matter of opinion.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwTA9hEBneAvPAORTAC2AlgHbHwA+JArriDMQNwBQoksCKdPABKAeQAyAUQDKhEgEEAIgFkAkgDk6jYgFVpk4Zy5cAZk2phElTNSSYdqdDADCUVgB4AKvBAAPRCDUwPi4iDA0AOYAfAAUoTAAXPCeAJRJDk5gbiBeUfAA3lzwxfBwiEwwtvEAdIj2jmyurDEp8G7wGWxZHp5RXAC+xmA2oaVJWDj4RKQUNEbD1KPCSWJSskR1nS7ZMTAp3FxAA)

Comment: The issue with my code was it didn't cater for the case the value is not in the range but `Uppercase<role>` gives me the guarantee I need so later if I add one more value to `role` but missed to add it to `ROLES`, TS will error out.